# Improve the performance on inner for loop in Javascript

Tags: loops

Can anyone help with improving the inner for loop?  I tried many different ways and I could not get it any faster.  I had a HackerRank problem and I kept getting a message for a few test cases that the test did not complete in the time allowed.

```
function minSum(num, k) {
    console.time("totaltime");
    // Write your code here   
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        let maxValue = num[0];
        let maxIndex = 0;
        //maxIndex = num.indexOf(Math.max(...num)); // 3517.743ms
         for (let j = 1; j < num.length; j++) { // 661.414ms
            if (num[j] > maxValue) {
                maxIndex = j;
                maxValue = num[j];
            }
        }
        num[maxIndex] = Math.ceil( num[maxIndex] / 2);        
    }
    console.timeEnd("totaltime");
    return num.reduce((pv, cv) => pv + cv, 0);
}
    const arr = [6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99, 100, 105, 1000, 3000, 5000, 67,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99, 100, 105, 1000, 3000, 5000, 67,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99, 100, 105, 1000, 3000, 5000, 67,
  6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 10, 25, 100, 39, 38 ,17, 0, 44, 99, 100, 105, 1000, 3000, 5000, 67
  ];
const k=950000;
console.log(minSum(arr, k));
```

Comment: if you can show us what you've already tried that could be very useful :) And describing whalt you actually want to do would be nice. To improve your calculation it would be necessary to understand exactlly what you're trying to achieve maybe you could already use some usefull math and get better performance

Comment: It would be better to use a different variable name for the innner loop: `j` is traditional.

Comment: Which hackerrank problem?

Comment: I had to take a test in HackerRank but after the test was over I could not find the problem in HackerRank.  Basically you have an array of integers and take the maximum integer in the array and divide by 2 and take the ceil value of that result and replace the maximum integer in the array with the new value.  You do this k (number of times) input value passed in.